# VirtualQueryEx unable to read memory, so can't dereference pointer (LPCVOID/uint8_t*)

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I have a function to read the memory of an application

```cpp
template<class T>
std::unordered_map<uint8_t, T> find_byte(T find) {
    std::cout << "Searching for value\n";

    std::unordered_map<uint8_t, T> mapping;

    // Turn the T bytes to a vector to use nice C++ functions
    std::vector<uint8_t> byte_check;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        byte_check = std::vector<uint8_t>(find.begin(), find.end());
    }
    else {
        uint8_t* data = static_cast<uint8_t*>(static_cast<void*>(&find));
        byte_check    = std::vector<uint8_t>(data, data + sizeof(find));
    }

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
    for (uint8_t* addr = nullptr; VirtualQueryEx(m_proc, addr, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info); addr += info.RegionSize) {
        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) {
            size_t read{};
            std::vector<uint8_t> mem_chunk;
            mem_chunk.resize(info.RegionSize);
            if (ReadProcessMemory(m_proc, addr, mem_chunk.data(), mem_chunk.size(), &read)) {
                mem_chunk.resize(read);
                for (auto pos = mem_chunk.begin();
                     mem_chunk.end() != (pos = std::search(pos, mem_chunk.end(), byte_check.begin(), byte_check.end()));
                     pos++) {
                    uint8_t* int_addr_ptr  = (addr + (pos - mem_chunk.begin()));
                    mapping[*int_addr_ptr] = find;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

It compiles just fine, however, it crashes it tries to dereference the `int_addr_ptr` pointer.
After stepping through with a debugger, I noticed that the `addr` returned from `VirtualQueryEx` was unable to be read.

I assume the issue lies in how I dereference, but I don't know how to fix it.
I have tired:

```cpp
auto lpcvoid       = (addr + (pos - mem_chunk.begin()));
auto int_addr_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(lpcvoid);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063283/c-reading-values-of-lpcvoid-pointer), but it yielded no results.

I want to note that if I return a map of `<uint8_t, T>` it works fine, but wanted to avoid the pointers

Comment: *addr* - address in remote process address space. as result *int_addr_ptr* (which is based on *addr*) too. so **int_addr_ptr* error

Comment: @RbMm How would I go about representing the remote address space as an int? I mean I assume the address is still a memory address that can be represented as a hex/int, even if relative to a different address space

Comment: address not fit to *int* in case 64bit. possible use *INT_PTR* for example (cast address to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query a memory region, you should start scanning through its content from its `BaseAddress`, not from the `addr`ess that you actually queried.  `VirtualQueryEx()` may have to round down the address.  `info.RegionSize` is relative to `info.BaseAddress`, so when calling `ReadProcessMemory()`, `mem_chunk.size()` will be too many bytes to read if `addr > info.BaseAddress`, you would need to subtract that offset from the size being read.

In the `std::search()` loop, `pos` should be incremented by the size of `find` that is being searched for, not by 1 byte.  And `addr` should again be `info.BaseAddress`.

But more importantly, why is `int_addr_ptr` being dereferenced *at all*?  Its value represents a memory address *in another process*, not in *your own process*.  So, you can't simply dereference it to read a value, doing so will try to read the value from *your process*.  If you want to read the value stored at that address, you will have to use `ReadProcessMemory()` instead.  But, what is `mapping` supposed to be keying off of exactly?  Why are you dereferencing `int_addr_ptr` to read a byte for a `mapping` key? Shouldn't you be keying the actual *addresses* where each copy of `find` is found?  And what is the point of storing copies of `find` in the `mapping`?

A simpler `vector<void*>` would make more sense, since the caller already knows the `find` value it is searching for, so no need to repeat it in the output.

As an added optimization, I would suggest getting rid of the `byte_check` vector altogether, as it is an unnecessary memory allocation.  You are using it only to have iterators for use with `std::search()`.  Raw pointers are also valid iterators.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::vector<void*> find_value(const T &find) {
    std::cout << "Searching for value\n";

    std::vector<void*> found;
    std::vector<uint8_t> mem_chunk;

    const uint8_t *find_begin, *find_end;
    size_t find_size;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        find_begin = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(find.c_str());
        find_size = find.size();
    }
    else {
        find_begin = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&find);
        find_size = sizeof(find);
    }

    find_end = find_begin + find_size;

    uint8_t *addr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0), *base;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(m_proc, addr, &info, sizeof(info))) {
        base = static_cast<uint8_t*>(info.BaseAddress);

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) {
            mem_chunk.reserve(info.RegionSize);

            size_t read;
            if (ReadProcessMemory(m_proc, info.BaseAddress, mem_chunk.data(), info.RegionSize, &read)) {
                auto start = mem_chunk.data(),
                     end = start + read,
                     pos = start;

                if (addr > base) {
                    pos += (addr - base);
                }

                while ((pos = std::search(pos, end, find_begin, find_end)) != end) {
                    found.push_back(base + (pos - start));
                    pos += find_size;
                }
            }
        }

        addr = base + info.RegionSize;
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: You bring out many good points but to answer a few of your design questions.
I chose a map as I will update those values at a later stage. Go through the map and update the values, so this is just the initial map. The idea was that the map key would be an int that I can turn into a hex, to show memory address ie. (0x423a23a1) or whatever, I could do the translation later, but I though right there made sense.
Also the initial design was base of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494340/how-to-perform-advanced-search-of-all-process-memory-from-visual-studio-debugger)

Comment: @TomasBerger you don't need a `map` for that. A `vector` of `void*` will work for that. You can display the `void*` as-is. And you will need the `void*`s if you intend to alter the memory later with `WriteProcessMemory()`.